# Does svelte can't get script like <script src='./fullcalendar/main.js'></script> from head?

Tags: fullcalendar, svelte

I using Svelte and FullCalendar to make a calendar in my front.
I used the code like this

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
      });
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <link href='./fullcalendar/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='./fullcalendar/main.js'></script>
</svelte:head>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

But It didn't worked at all

I used svelte:head to put the script and link in it. But It says it can't identify(find name) FullCalendar whiched worked in original javascript file(myCallendar.js <- I made this)

I also putted it in the index.html file or put the fullcalendar folder(cdn files) near the src and changed the paths, but they didn't worked.
I really wanted to use it but unfortunately it only has the react, vue version not svelte one.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: document.addEventListener might be running in your server during ssr, which is not what you want, and by the time the event is added it is already loaded.

What you can do is listen to load event on the script tag. [This repl might help](https://svelte.dev/repl/c92078e516574fe59d7770f07c0903b6?version=3.16.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Svelte, `DomContentLoaded` isn't the ideal way to make sure the component is mounted. Use onMount instead. See example below. If you don't want to use onMount, you can also just wait for the element to load using `$: if(calendarEl) {//do stuff here}`

Also, you can just `bind` the element to a variable to get the reference to it, instead of calling `document.getElementById`. Finally, `var` isn't used in modern JS - use `const` or `let`.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/9ac6f5a22eeb4d32bf3bca9197e43d1f?version=3.53.1

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from "svelte"
    const calendarEl = undefined;
    

    onMount(() => {
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
    })

</script>

<svelte:head>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.js'></script>
</svelte:head>

<div id='calendar' bind:this={calendarEl}></div>
```